# Get pages attribute by system call in Linux

Tags: linux

Is there any system call or function that can get page attribute like readable, writable, executable by page address? 
I know we can use mprotect to set pages attribute, but I have no idea if we can get pages attribute. Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't. You need to use the proc interface, which contains lots of information about each process in various files. The information you're looking for is in plaintext, in `/proc/<pid>/maps`. You can take a look at it for your current process by running:

```
$ cat /proc/$$/maps
```

You can find some more information in [man 5 proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc).

The example given at the above link is:

```
address           perms offset  dev   inode   pathname
08048000-08056000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
08056000-08058000 rw-p 0000d000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
08058000-0805b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
40000000-40013000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so
40013000-40015000 rw-p 00012000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so
4001f000-40135000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
40135000-4013e000 rw-p 00115000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
4013e000-40142000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
bffff000-c0000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
```

As you can see, the permissions are the second (space-delimited) field there. So from a program (like in `C`, since you mentioned `mprotect()`, you could open up `/proc/$$/maps` with `fopen()`, then use `fgets()` or `scanf()` to pull the data out. You're just looking for that `perms` field of the range where your page lies.

Comment: @jørgensen Absolutely! Though OP was only looking for simple permissions on a given page.